# onclicklistener not working for dynamically created customview

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener

i have class StickerImageView that extand StickerView class and StickerView extend 
FrameLayout

now i'm creating object of StickerImageView class and setup bitmap into it..

```
StickerImageView iv_sticker;
iv_sticker = new StickerImageView(this);
iv_sticker.setImageBitmap(result);
```

and making it visible to screen by adding view

```
mainscreen_relativelayout.addView(iv_sticker);
```

now i want to detact toast on that dynamically created view(iv_sticker) so i'm doing this

```
iv_sticker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"i clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

i also tried this for this custom view iv_sticker

```
iv_sticker.setClickable(true);
```

when i use OnTouchListener toast appear but view(iv_sticker) not getting movable anymore

```
iv_sticker.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            Toast.makeText(CropActivity.this,"i clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Do what you want
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

this is log when i click on sticker

```
04-07 18:03:23.265 8208-8208/com.package.myappname V/com.knef.stickerView: sticker view action down
04-07 18:03:23.362 8208-8208/com.package.myappname V/PhoneWindow: debug app launch: MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
04-07 18:03:23.362 8208-8208/com.package.myappname V/com.knef.stickerView: sticker view action up
```

Comment: What do you mean bu 'Not Working', Do you get an error? if so, please post them.

Comment: no i'm not getting any error

Comment: So what's up? did you debug the program? does the code goes into the OnClick Method and the toast just doesn't show or it doesnt even get into the OnClick method?

Comment: i posted my log when i click on sticker it's showing MotionEvent.ACTION_UP

Comment: Can you try to debug your program and tell me if the code enters the OnClick method?

Comment: Have u given ontouchevent on the stickerview

Comment: @ FlyingNades , code not enter in onclick method

Comment: @ R.Anjali  when i try ontouchevent , toast appear but sticker is not movable anymore

Comment: @KamaleshM.Talaviya, How did you solve this?

Comment: @Ajay J G sorry I can not help you brother, right now I moved to PHP, I no longer working on Android and i doesn't remember solution that I tried.

Answer (score 0):

> when i try ontouchevent , toast appear but sticker is not movable
>   anymore

This is because you have consumed the touch event. Return `false` from the `onTouch(...)` method to make framework handle it for you again.

Comment: after returning false onTouch from  onTouch , toast not appearing and sticker also not moving